# How can I nest two custom storybook decorator to create another one?

Tags: reactjs, decorator, storybook

I have two decorators:

```
const withDecorator1 = (story, options) => {
    // do something with the options
    return <>{story()}</>
});

const withDecorator2 = (story, options) => {
    // do something with the options
    return <>{story()}</>
});
```

I now want to compose a third decorator by nesting these two.

Answer (score 0):

**I detail how I achieved it below**

First two decorators:

```
const withDecorator1 = (story, options) => {
    // do something with the options
    return <>{story()}</>
});

const withDecorator2 = (story, options) => {
    // do something with the options
    return <>{story()}</>
});
```

Third decorator (derived):

```
const withDecorator1And2 = (story, options) => {
  return withDecorator2(() => {
    return withDecorator1(story, options);
  }, options)
};
```

The key is to ensure that the `story` funtion is called by the last decorator.

Also, the order matters. If one decorator depends on another, it should be called first. For example in the case `withDecorator1And2` above, `withDecorator1` depends on `withDecorator2`.